# Nginx HLS Load balancer data traffic on primary server

Tags: nginx

My design is:
Media Server -> edge servers (Multiple Nginx Cache server -> Nginx Load Balancer)
it is my private CDN system (for Live content delivery)
I have content source and multiple edges; in each edge, there is multiple cache server and a Load Balancer
I started step by step, so for this job I face a problem with Nginx Load Balancer.
In this configuration, I am balancing between two servers s1 and s2.
but when I check traffic by(nload), I see big traffic on the primary server(load balancer) for example from  nload see s1=1GBPS s2=1GBPS loadbalancer=2GBPS
note: my content is HLS (.m3u8)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    include    mime.types;
    include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile     on;
    tcp_nopush   on;

    # upstream
    upstream origins {
      server s1.ip;
      server s2.ip;
    }


    # default route
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  example.com;
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com  main;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://origins;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the load balancer's traffic is the sum of its upstream servers' traffic, because that's what a simple [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) does. Maybe you need a different architecture like [round robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).

Comment: if a simple load balancer is like that, so what's the benefit of it ??

Comment: Your architecture works well if the upstream servers need to do a lot of work to generate a response. It sounds like you want something that's more like a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), something like Cloudflare?.